# Error 500 when trying to post file via WebApi 2

Tags: vb.net, api, iis, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-500

I've made a simple WebApi 2 POST method that receive and store files in a folder the API looks like the following:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http

    Public Class XmlController
        Inherits ApiController

        <HttpPost()>
        Public Function PostXml() As HttpResponseMessage
            If Request.Headers.Contains("authToken") Then
                If Request.Headers.GetValues("authToken").First() <> "XXX" Then Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            End If

            Dim httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request

            If httpRequest.Files.Count > 0 Then

                For Each fileName As String In httpRequest.Files.Keys
                    Dim file = httpRequest.Files(fileName)
                    Dim filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Tavoli/" & file.FileName)
                    file.SaveAs(filePath)
                Next

                Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)
            End If

            Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End Function
    End Class
```

If I run the .NET Framework application in local and try to post a file via POSTMAN to `http://localhost:53790/api/xml` all works fine but when I post the website on my server and then try to use the same POSTMAN request by changing localhost to my domain it returns 500 Internal Server Error, I've tried to uncheck "Read-Only" from the folder but it had no effect.. The website is running on IIS and other POST calls to other API's works fine (the other calls are just JSON)

Comment: Does the user that IIS is running under have access to the folder?

Comment: @theduck i think so i'm logged as administrator https://imgur.com/HBfazcx here are properties of Tavoli folder

Comment: You see the IIS_USRS user at the bottom of the list. Does that user have write permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the user that IIS runs under (often `IIS_USRS`) has write permission to the folder you are trying to write your files to.